# Detect when odoo interface is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-8

I need to run some javascript code to check when odoo has ended loading.

I know that querying **jQuery.active == 0** does the trick in version 7 but that does not work in odoo because it always keep one connection open for the longpolling.

Does anybody know which web element can I use to check for sure when the interface is fully loaded ?

If I can query the URL of the active jQuery connections that would also do the trick.

Comment: What about $(window).load() ?

Comment: well then you need to post some existing code. we can't assume what is happening at your end. yet i want to tell you that if there are some async calls then you can use `$.when().then()` to chain it to proceed in a chained manner.

Comment: I am trying to do this: 

http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/selenium-wait-for-ajax-the-right-way/

The code is there in step 5: 

selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0

Comment: I need to check the condition at any time, in order to know if odoo is not expecting responses from the server (other than longpolling request, of course)

Comment: open the javascript console of the browser with CTRL+SHIFT+I when odoo is loaded and quiet. If you can put there a javascript expression that evaluates to true and would evaluate to false while loading something of the interface, the problem is solved.

Comment: @yucer you got some advance?

Comment: @Jai : I have added no custom code to odoo, since i am trying to test it. You can try the last release of odoo v8. I am just looking for a JavaScript expression to check one condition: "Odoo interface is quiet and nothing remains to load". This "quiet" concept exclude the longpolling requests for instant messaging.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen please read my answer to oMiKey's question.

Comment: @yucer Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem in Odoo v9

Comment: No, I did not. I have to make some time to solve this. As a temporary solution we try more times. The solution would allow to safe resource usage during tests.

It helps a little to disable the chron jobs while making the tests. Also anything that can Introduce random extra time.

Comment: I was trying something with the $.ajaxPrefilter(). But I have to elaborate it more.

Answer (score 7):

I don´t know odoo but I supose that you can wait for a variable in odoo and do this:

```
function checkodoo() {
   if ('undefined' !== typeof odooVariableThatYouWatch ) {
       clearInterval(intervalOdoo);
       lauchYourStaff();
   }
}

var intervalOdoo = setInterval("checkodoo()",100);
```

If on https://www.odoo.com the variable is  **openerp**

I look the variable here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html

Comment: Do you mean that the openerp variable is destroyed on every user interaction (Ex: a user clicks on a menu item) and it's the last element to be assigned after all needed elements are reloaded ?

Comment: By the way... The question is not about waiting. It's about the expression to wait for. Would your answer be 'undefined' !== typeof openerp ?